# Highest weight states in a free bosonic 2D CFT

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, conformal-field-theory

From the state-operator correspondence we know that each highest weight state (radial quantization) can be thought of being created by a primary field $\phi(0)$ at the origin. Upon raise/lower operations, highest weight states lead to descendent states, which gives the complete structure of the Hilbert space.

For example, for a free bosonic field theory $\mathcal{L}(\varphi)$, the Hilbert space can be thought of as a Fock space, with continuous "vacuum" states given by the vertex operator $:e^{i\alpha \varphi}:$. Vacuum states are highest weight states, and excited states in the Fock space correspond to the descendent states.

This gives a nice picture of the Hilbert space structure. However, we know that $\partial \varphi(z)$ is also a primary field, which by the state-operator correspondence should also create a highest weight state. My question is, where does this state fits into the Fock space picture?

Comment: Polchinski Vol. 1, Chapter 2, Section 2.8, Equation (2.8.7)

Comment: I would even point to the definition (2.7.1). In Laurent expansion of the operator around $z=0$, the term responsible for creation of the state is the constant term. For $\partial \varphi(z)$ such term is $a_{-1}$. In other words, $\partial \varphi(0)$ creates the state with zero spacetime momentum and a single "right-moving" excitation.

Comment: Thanks @mavzolej, how do you formally justify the normal ordering, i.e., throwing out $a_{-n}, n>1$ terms in the mode expansion?

Comment: See "Asymptotic states" on page 22 in ["Introduction to CFT" by Blumenhagen and Plauschinn](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=540D85CE928A45EE963AEDAF4AE3009C). In short - negative powers are unphysical due to divergence, positive powers vanish themselves.

Comment: @mavzolej Thanks, I get this logic, but I still feel somewhat uncomfortable.

Comment: @mavzolej One way to justify this is to replace $\phi(0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\phi(z)$ with $\phi(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{C\to 0}\int_C \frac{dz}{z}\phi(z)$, an angular average of $\phi(z)$ around a infinitesimally small circle $C$, this yields the normal ordering and seems logically clearer.

Comment: @mavzolej just realized for free bosons the issue is much simpler: the divergent terms $\sim a_n z^{-n-1}$ are with $a_0$ or anihilation operators! So these terms acting on vacuum doesn't contribute to the in state.

Comment: A good point ☝️